# wkhtmltopdf not rendering canvas and svg elements

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am converting HTML to PDF with **wkhtmltopdf-i386** on **Ubuntu 11.10**. 
Using **PHP** and help code from http://mikehaertl.github.io/phpwkhtmltopdf/
With simple **HTML** and text it is working fine but But HTML script with **SVG** and **Canvas** render Blank result means PDF generating but blank.

Answer (score 0):

Make You sure, that You have scr path correctly.
In my case I have:

```
/* rendering to pdf */
$pdf = new Pdf;
$pdf->addPage('

<html>
<head>
<style>
#image{ width:300px; }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div> AHOJ</div>
<div id="image">
<img src="/mnt/databox/www/myweb/pdf/G6-interactive.svg">
</div>

')
```

and SVG is rendered into PDF correctly,
In past I have had similar problem because of src path